# MySQL performance problem using indexed datetime column

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, myisam, datetime

I tried to solve the following problem for about one hour now and still didn't get any further with it.

Okay, I have  a table (MyISAM):

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| http    | smallint(3) | YES  | MUL | 200               |                |
| elapsed | float(6,3)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| cached  | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| ip      | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| date    | timestamp   | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Please don't mind the indexes, I've been playing around trying to find a solution. Now, here's my query.

```
SELECT http,
COUNT( http )  AS count 
FROM reqs
WHERE DATE(date) >= cast(date_sub(date(NOW()),interval 24 hour) as datetime)
GROUP BY http
ORDER BY count;
```

the table is storing information about incoming web requests so its a rather big database.

```
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|    782412 |
+-----------+
```

note that there's no better way of setting a primary key as the *id* column will be the only unique identifier I have. The above mentioned query takes  about 0.6-1.6 seconds to run.

Which index would be clever? I figured that indexing *date* will give me "bad" cardinality and thus MySQL won't use it. *http* is also a bad choice as there are only about 20 different possible values.

Thanks for you help!

**Update 1** I've added an index on *(http, date)* as ypercube suggested:

```
mysql> CREATE INDEX httpDate ON reqs (http, date);
```

and used his query, but it performed equally bad. The added index:

```
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| reqs  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |      798869 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| reqs  |          1 | httpDate |            1 | http        | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| reqs  |          1 | httpDate |            2 | date        | A         |       99858 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

and the *EXPLAIN*

```
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                                     |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | r     | range | NULL          | httpDate | 3       | NULL |    20 | Using index for group-by; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ri    | ref   | httpDate      | httpDate | 3       | func | 41768 | Using where; Using index                                  |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

MySQL server version:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value               |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| protocol_version        | 10                  |
| version                 | 5.1.73              |
| version_comment         | Source distribution |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64              |
| version_compile_os      | redhat-linux-gnu    |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you also add the mysql version and what is the engine of the table? (myisam or innodb)

Comment: MyISAM and 5.1.73 - all details now in the post.

Comment: I'm afraid it may have to do with the `http` column being nullable. I'll investigate tomorrow, if I find time.

Comment: I'm afraid it may have to do with the http column being nullable. I'll investigate tomorrow, if I find time. You can test by creating an identical table (except with `http NOT NULL`) and copying all data to it (except the rows with http NULL of course.)

Comment: Changing it to NOT NULL (which is entirely possible, I didn't mind it much when creating the table) boosted performance to about ~1s - 1.6s for the query (my query). Thanks for your effort until now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have three suggestions

## SUGGESTION #1 : Rewrite the query

You should rewrite the query as follows

```
SELECT http,
COUNT( http )  AS count 
FROM reqs
WHERE date >= ( DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND )
GROUP BY http
ORDER BY count;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT http,
    COUNT( http )  AS count 
    FROM reqs
    WHERE date >= ( DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND )
    GROUP BY http
) A ORDER BY count;
```

The WHERE should not have a function on both sides of the equal sign. Having date on the left side of the equals sign makes it easier for the Query Optimizer to use an index against it.

## SUGGESTION #2 : Supporting Index

I would also suggest a different index

```
ALTER TABLE reqs ADD INDEX date_http_ndx (date,http); -- not (http,date)
```

I suggest this order of columns because the `date` entries would all be contiguous in the index. Then, the query simply collects `http` values without skipping gaps in `http`.

## SUGGESTION #3 : Bigger Key Buffer (Optional)

MyISAM only uses index caching. Since the query should not touch the `.MYD` file, you should use a slightly bigger MyISAM Key Buffer.

To set it to 256M

```
SET @newsize = 1024 * 1024 * 256;
SET GLOBAL key_buffer_size = @newsize;
```

Then, set it in `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
key_buffer_size = 256M
```

Restart of MySQL not required

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I tried the queries you gave me. #1 performed about as good as the other suggestion or my own, the second one actually performed worse. Same thing for the Supporting Index - make the performance drop about 75 percent. I'm going to try the bigger key buffer now, thank you anyways!

Comment: I accepted your answer although it didn't fix the problem, with a bigger key buffer however it performed somewhat better. Closing this as it's the best soluion of all given. Thank you!

Comment: For Suggestion #2 to work, it may be necessary to add "USE INDEX" or "FORCE INDEX" in the query, at least that is what I had to do in order to speed up my query after creating an index like that.

Answer (score -2):

Change your date column type to an integer. Store the date as a Unix date in integer. Timestamp Is a lot larger than an int. You'd get some bang out of that.

Comment: Are you kidding? Both `INT` and `TIMESTAMP` need 4 bytes.

Comment: Not ot mention that you lose all the datetime functions when you are storing dates or timestamps as integers.